# How i insert values from a dropdwonlist on a listview using the inserted of sqldatasource

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I have a table client and another table named hoobie and this two has a relationship n...n, i tried to insert a new client and just AFTER i inserted the client i was to insert the hoobie of the new client using the last_id...i tried to do all of this on the inserted of my sqldatasource... but it is not working!!

```
code in C#...and the control's was in ASP.NET:
```

the hobbies was represented in a dropdown list...i use to insert then a list view

```
protected void databaseClient_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)listviewClient.InsertItem.NamingContainer.FindControl("dropdwonHobbies");

        var Connection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost,database=dreamlive,pwd='',user=root");

        Connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO client_hobbies (id_hobbie,id_client) VALUES (@id_hobbie,LAST_INSERT_ID())", Connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("id_hobbie", e.Command.Parameters["dropdwonHobbies"].Value);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connection.Close();

}
```

Comment: The error :"Parameter 'dropdwonHobbies' not found in the collection"

Comment: To begin with, check for the typo en dropd**wo**nHobbies